# Code block not rendering properly with docusaurus

Tags: mdx, monorepo, docusaurus, turborepo, prism-react-renderer

Does anyone know of any incompatibilities between docusaurus when working with monorepo tools. I'm having issues getting code blocks to render properly in my docs, however the exact same code works fine outside the monorepo. I am using turborepo btw, incase this might be tool specific.

Does anyone know of any incompatibilities between docusaurus when working with monorepo tools. I'm having issues getting code blocks to render properly in my docs, however the exact same code works fine outside the monorepo. I am using turborepo btw, incase this might be tool specific.